# ffi-napi failing to load .dll - running on mac os

Tags: node.js, dllimport, dylib

I'm trying to load .dll in simple js file, following official docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi).

If I try from official doc this, it works

```
var ffi = require('ffi-napi');

var libm = ffi.Library('libm', {
  'ceil': [ 'double', [ 'double' ] ]
});
libm.ceil(1.5); // 2

// You can also access just functions in the current process by passing a null
var current = ffi.Library(null, {
  'atoi': [ 'int', [ 'string' ] ]
});
console.log(current.atoi('1234')); // 1234
```

But if I try to load the provided .dll that I have in the same folder as the dll.js file - the code looks like this

```
const ffi = require('ffi-napi');
const path = require('path');

const file = path.join(__dirname, '/testLibrary');

const pos = ffi.Library(file, {
  testFunction: ['void', ['int']],
});
```

I get this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:serialPortTest martin$ node dll.js 
/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/node_modules/ffi-napi/lib/dynamic_library.js:75
    throw new Error('Dynamic Linking Error: ' + err);
    ^

Error: Dynamic Linking Error: dlopen(/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/testLibrary.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/testLibrary.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/testLibrary.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/testLibrary.dylib' (no such file)
    at new DynamicLibrary (/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/node_modules/ffi-napi/lib/dynamic_library.js:75:11)
    at Object.Library (/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/node_modules/ffi-napi/lib/library.js:47:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/dll.js:6:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.18.2
```

I'm confused by the .dylib extension that is added there automatically.

I tried to add .dll extension, but then in the log I can see `/Users/martin/Projects/serialPortTest/testLibrary.dll.dylib`.

I stackoverflowed/googled it as I could, but nothing helped.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What "provided `.dll`" is this? DLL as an extension is a Windows thing; you can't just use DLLs automagically on macOS.

Comment: It's from vendor for integrating Point of Sale Terminal. With ffi-napi I should be able to load the functions from the .dll in node.js. If the usage is limited to Windows, I'm ok with that as the final solution will be running on local Windows, but I work/develop on MacOS.

Comment: Then you will need to develop on a virtual Windows too, unfortunately. You can't simply use a Windows DLL on macOS – even more so if you're on Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't load a Windows DLL on macOS for a variety of reasons, including but not limited to: Windows-specific things the DLL may depend on, the binary file format (Mach-O vs PE), the CPU architecture the DLL has been compiled against (especially so if you're on Apple Silicon).

If you need to develop a solution against a Windows-specific DLL, you will need to use Windows – either virtualized or not.